# Login con Estado? Laravel

Tags: laravel

Buenas he personalizado el login que ofrece el mismo laravel, puedo ingresar todo correctamente pero ahora he agregado una nueva columna a la tabla de los usuarios que se llama `Estado` en donde si tiene un `0` esta activo y si tiene un `1` esta desactivado. Entonces he intentado que al momento de que se logee el usuario y contraseña solo pueda ingresar al sistema si su Estado es 0 y si su Estado es 1 que no ingrese pero igual ingresa al sistema por mas que tenga el estado desactivado.

-Codigo del Controller LoginController:

```
public function login(Request $request){
        $credentials = $this->validate($request,[
            'Usuario' =>'required|string',
            'Clave' =>'required|string'
        ]);

        $credenciales = [
            'Usuario' => $credentials['Usuario'],
            'password' => $credentials['Clave']
        ];

        if(Auth::attempt($credenciales) && Auth::user()->Estado == 0){
            return redirect('/');
        }else{
            return back()->withErrors([$this->username()=>'Estas credenciales no concuerdan con nuestros registros']);
          }
    }
```

Yo agrege `Auth::user()->Estado == 0` porque buscado en otras preguntas salia eso como respuesta pero igual no me sale. Como puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las condiciones adicionales tendrías que pasarselas también al método `attempt()`, puedes agregarlo en el array `$credenciales`:

```php
$credenciales = [
    'Usuario' => $credentials['Usuario'],
    'password' => $credentials['Clave'],
    'Estado' => 0,
];

if(Auth::attempt($credenciales)){
    // Authentication passed...
    return redirect()->intended('/');
}
```

Fuente: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Oh, y yo estaba entrando dentro de la ruta donde se encunetra el metodo attempt, gracias!