# Quiero iniciar sesion en laravel con usuario, contraseña y una sucursal

Tags: laravel, session, relaciones

soy relativamente nuevo en laravel y lo que deseo es que un usuario al iniciar sesión, tambien corresponda a una sucursal que tiene dicho usuario y si no selecciona su sucursal correcta, no pueda entrar. Mi base de datos es la siguiente:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 40);
            $table->string('foto', 255);
            $table->string('email',25)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('puesto');
            $table->foreign('puesto')->references('id')->on('puestos');
            $table->string('usuario', 20);
            $table->string('password', 255);
            $table->string('calle', 255);
            $table->string('telefono', 10);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('idSucursal');
            $table->foreign('idSucursal')->references('id')->on('destinos');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```php
Schema::create('destinos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nombre', 50);
            $table->string('direccion', 200);
            $table->string('telefono', 10);
            $table->string('ciudad', 50);
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

este es el controller:

```php
//Esta parte es para cambiar de email a usuario
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $login = $request->input($this->username());
        // Comprobar si el input coincide con el formato de E-mail
        $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)? 'email':'usuario';
        return [
        $field => $login,
        'password' => $request->input('password')
        ];
    }
    public function username()
    {
        return 'login';
    }
```

y esta es la vista:

```
<label>Usuario</label>
                  <form class="user" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" method="POST">
                      @csrf 
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">  <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="login" type="login" class="form-control @error('login') is-invalid @enderror" name="login" value="{{ old('login') }}" required autocomplete placeholder="Introduce tu usuario" autofocus">

                        @error('login')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                                               </div>



                    <label>Contraseña</label>
                      <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">  <i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                      </div>

                    <label>Sucursal</label>
                      <div class = "input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text" id = "basic-addon1"> <i class="fas fa-store"></i>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        <select name ="sucursal" id= "id_destino" class="form-control @error('sucursal') is-invalid @enderror" required>
                          <option> --Selecciona tu sucursal-- </option>
                          <option id= "1"> Sucursal Almacen Central</option>
                          <option id= "2"> Sucursal Almacen Capital</option>
                          <option id= "3"> Sucursal Carrillo</option>
                          <option id= "4"> Sucursal Centro Histórico</option>
                          <option id= "5"> Sucursal Zamora</option>
                          <option id= "6"> Sucursal Pátzcuaro</option>
                          <option id= "7"> Sucursal La Huerta</option>
                          <option id= "8"> Sucursal Estadio</option>
                        </select>
                        @error('sucursal')
                          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                        @enderror
                      </div>
```

Metodo user.php:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'puesto', 'usuario', 'id_destino', 'telefono','numerodir', 'calle', 'foto'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

UsersController:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Closure;
use App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;



class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('puestos', 'puestos.id', '=', 'users.puesto')
            ->join('destinos', 'destinos.id', '=', 'users.idSucursal')
            ->select('users.*', 'puestos.descripcion', 'destinos.nombre')

                            ->orderBy('puestos.id', 'asc')

            ->paginate(4);
        return view('users', compact('users'));


    }
```

Entonces lo que deseo es saber al momento de que el usuario seleccione su sucursal la valide con el usuario que está entrando y de acceso si el usuario pertenece a esa sucursal además de que la sucursal que seleccione se guarde como variable ya que la usaré mas adelante para mostrar la información de esa sucursal que seleccionó. Ya logre que cada usuario tenga su rol y permisos, pero me falta eso de la sucursal desde el login, si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu modelo Users?

Comment: o mas simple, agrega la funcion username y retorna el campo con el que quieres que inicie sesion asi mismo una verificacion para la sucursual, esto lo tienes que hacer en el LoginController.php

Comment: Dohko, ya esta el metodo user

Comment: Como haría lo segundo que dices @Dohko19

Comment: Pero tu retornas 'login'

Comment: @Dohko19 si, para realizar un login con usuario y contraseña, está mal?

Comment: Laravel por defecto en el trait AuthenticateUsers, llama a la funcion username si al revisas tiene esto, ´   public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }´ ---- osease que laravel toma el email como una referencia para iniciar sesion mas aparte la contraseña

Comment: No entiendo porque le pusiste 'login' al name para el inicio de sesiòn no esta mal pero para que tu codigo sea mas claro debes poner Username o name, esto ultimo es una sugerencia, como puedes ver no tienes que hacer gran cosa, solo agregar un campo con el cual el usuario realizara login en vez del email, adecuar tus inputs y realizar la verificacion con la sucursal

Comment: Tienes razon, no lo vi, entonces en mi login controller, ya no lo llamo? y modifico lo que me dijiste de tu segundo comentario?

Comment: te sugiero que primero cambies la funcion que tienes de username() el return que haces por 'name' ya que laravel intentara buscar un campo en la bd con ese identificador, pruebes que funcione y pasas al otro tema de la sucursal

Comment: tal vez esta pregunta respuesta te sirva para ver como pasar condiciones adicionales al Auth::attempt en el método Login https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/295596/login-con-estado-laravel/295630#295630

Answer (score 1):

No veo que publicaste el método para login, ahi en ese método 1ro chekea si las credenciales son correctas y si lo son compruebas si es de la sucursal que le corresponde, pero 1ro que todo crea el modelo Sucursal y luego relaciona el modelo User con el de Sucursal.

Esto en el modelo User

```
public function sucursal()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Sucursal::class, 'idSucursal', 'id');
}
```

Luego en el controlador LoginController crea el método login

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        "email" => "required|email",
        "password" => "required",
    ]);
    $remember = $request->filled('remember');
    $user = User::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();

    if (isset($user->id)){
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            if ($user->sucursal->id == $request->sucursal ) {
                Auth::login($user, $remember);
                $request->session()->regenerate();
                return redirect()->intended('/');
            }
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'msg' => 'Seleccione a la sucursal que le pertenece',
            ]);
        }
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'msg' => 'credenciales incorrectas',
        ]);
    }
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'msg' => 'No hemos podido verificar tu cuenta con esa información.',
    ]);
}
```